# Create a dataframe from a loop that gets links from a google search

Tags: python, dataframe, google-search

I have the following code:

IN:

```
from googlesearch import search
query_list = ["Linkedin","Facebook","Instagram", "site oficial"]

company_name = input("Please provide the stock name:")

for j in query_list:
for i in search(company_name+j, tld='com.br', lang='pt-br', num=1, start=0, stop=1, 
pause=1.0):
    print (i)
```

OUT:

```
https://br.linkedin.com/company/havanoficial
https://www.facebook.com/Havanoficial/
https://www.instagram.com/havanoficial/
https://www.havan.com.br/
```

The problem is that I need these results in a DataFrame with 4 different columns. My desired output would be something like this:

| Linkedin | Facebook | Instagram | Website |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://br.linkedin.com/company/havanoficial | https://www.facebook.com/Havanoficial/ | https://www.instagram.com/havanoficial/ | https://www.havan.com.br/ |

Any tips? I really appreciate it! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
out = [
'https://br.linkedin.com/company/havanoficial/',
'https://www.facebook.com/Havanoficial/',
'https://www.instagram.com/havanoficial/',
'https://www.havan.com.br/',
]

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
df = df.T
df.columns = query_list
```

Result:

```
In [38]: df                                                                                                                                          
Out[38]: 
                                       Linkedin                                Facebook                                Instagram               site oficial
0  https://br.linkedin.com/company/havanoficial  https://www.facebook.com/Havanoficial/  https://www.instagram.com/havanoficial/  https://www.havan.com.br/
```